# Mousemove event with three.js and gsap

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, mouseevent, gsap

I am trying to do a mousemove event where the mesh would scale when the mouse hovers over it and then it goes back to its original size when the mouse no longer hovers above it. So I've been looking at other examples and they don,t use gsap. The closest one I've seen is tween.js so maybe my syntax is wrong but I don't know how to rectify it.

Here is my function

```
function onMouseMove(event) {
 //finding position of mouse
                event.preventDefault();
                mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
                mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
                raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse,camera);

      // meshes included in mousemove
                objects.push( mesh);
                objects.push( mesh2 );

//including objects into intersects

                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, true);

    //if statement for intersection
                if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

                    if ( intersects[ 0 ].object != INTERSECTED ) 
                    {
                        if ( INTERSECTED ) 
//gsap animation
                            INTERSECTED.gsap.to(intersects[0].object.scale, {duration: .7, x: 1.2, y:1.2});
                            INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;


                    }
                } else {// there are no intersections 
                        // restore previous intersection object to its original size
                        if ( INTERSECTED ) 
                        gsap.to(intersects[0].object.scale, {duration: .7, x: 1, y:1});

                            INTERSECTED = null;

                }
            }
```

With this I get an error:
**Cannot read property 'object' of undefined
    at onMouseMove**

But when I previously did a for loop with undefined `object`, the code works, but I just need it to scale down again

Here is my for loop:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
                    gsap.to(intersects[i].object.scale, {duration: .7, x: 1.2, y:1.2});
                };
```

EDIT:

created a fiddle, using the for loop but commented out the if statement:

```js
let camera, scene, renderer, cube, cube1;
let raycaster;
let mouse = new THREE.Vector2(), INTERSECTED;
const objects = [];


init();
animate();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100 );
    camera.position.z = 20;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(3,3,3);
    const material = new THREE. MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
     cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
     cube.position.y = 5;
    
    scene.add(cube);
    
    
    const geometry1 = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(3,3,3);
    const material1 = new THREE. MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
     cube1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry1, material1);
    
    scene.add(cube1);
    
    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
     renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
    window.addEventListener('mousemove',onMouseMove, false);
  
   
  }

    
  
  // animation
    
   function onMouseMove (event) {

   event.preventDefault();
  mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse,camera);

  //included in mousemove
 
   objects.push( cube );
            objects.push( cube1 );

   
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects, true);
  
  //working for loop
   for(var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++) {
        gsap.to(intersects[i].object.scale, {duration: .7, x: 1.2, y:1.2});
    }
    

    //not working if statement
    
    /*     
                if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

                    if ( intersects[ 0 ].object != INTERSECTED ) 
                    {
                        if ( INTERSECTED ) 
                            INTERSECTED.gsap.to(intersects[0].object.scale, {duration: .7, x: 1.2, y:1.2});
                            INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
                            
                            
                    }
                } else {// there are no intersections 
                        // restore previous intersection object (if it exists) to its original size
                        if ( INTERSECTED ) 
                        gsap.to(intersects[0].object.scale, {duration: .7, x: 1.2, y:1.2});
                       
                            INTERSECTED = null;
    
                }
                */
               
   }

   
   
   
function animate() {
 



  
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.114/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.2.4/dist/gsap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please demonstrate the issue with a live example? You can use the code from this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qz1afen9/

Comment: Hi @Mugen87. Here is my fiddle [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/xLd8jwag/) I have used the for loop to demonstrate my scale but I want it to scale down again when the mouse no longer hovers above the objects with gsap. I have commented out my if statement that I am trying to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with this updated code:

```js
let camera, scene, renderer, cube, cube1;
let raycaster;
let mouse = new THREE.Vector2(), INTERSECTED = null;
const objects = [];


init();
animate();

function init() {

 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100 );
 camera.position.z = 20;

 scene = new THREE.Scene();

 const geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 3, 3, 3 );
 const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
 cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
 cube.position.y = 5;

 scene.add( cube );

 const geometry1 = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 3, 3, 3 );
 const material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
 cube1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry1, material1 );

 scene.add( cube1 );

 raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
 renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
 renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
 document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

 window.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );

}

function onMouseMove( event ) {

 event.preventDefault();
 mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
 mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
 raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

 //included in mousemove

 objects.push( cube );
 objects.push( cube1 );


 var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, true );


 if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

  var object = intersects[ 0 ].object;

  if ( object !== INTERSECTED )   {

   INTERSECTED = object;
   gsap.to( INTERSECTED.scale, { duration: .7, x: 1.2, y: 1.2 } );
   

  }

 } else {
 
  if ( INTERSECTED !== null ) {
   
   gsap.to( INTERSECTED.scale, { duration: .7, x: 1, y: 1 } );
   INTERSECTED = null;
 
  }
 
 }

}


function animate() {

 requestAnimationFrame( animate );
 renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
}
canvas {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.114/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.2.4/dist/gsap.js"></script>
```